# How do I package source code for a web site and a database so that it can be referenced in a ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I've been looking at various articles around authoring ARM template files including [Authoring Azure Resource Manager Templates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/). That article explains how to author a template file to deploy a website assuming that that website has already been packaged into a .zip file and placed on Azure BLOB storage:

```
"properties": {
             "packageUri": "https://auxmktplceprod.blob.core.windows.net/packages/StarterSite-modified.zip",
             "dbType": "None",
             "connectionString": "",
             "setParameters": {
               "Application Path": "[parameters('siteName')]"
             }
```

What it doesn't explain is how an asp.net project can get packaged into that .zip file.

---

I have an ASP.net web project in Visual Studio. How do I package the build output from that ASP.net project so that it can be referenced in my ARM template?

Moreover my solution also consists of a database that is represented in a Visual Studio database project. Same question for that, how do I package the build output from that database project so that it can be referenced in my ARM template?

Comment: Ah, I created a reference to my ASP.Net project in my Azure Resource Group project (i.e. .deployproj) and the output from that project has been packaged into bin\debug\Artifacts\<ASP.Net project name>\package.zip. I think I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 0):

For the database you can put that into the webdeploy package as a dacpac and have WebDeploy do the deployment or you can create a bacpac and have the template deploy the database from the bacpac.

Comment: Hello Brian, yes I've since found this to be the case. I am bitterly disappointed that ARM does not support .dacpac deployment and have fed back that this needs to change.